# secret scanner in Azure DevOps repo

Tags: azure-devops, credentials, repo

Can you recommend an efficient scanner for secrets in code in an Azure DevOps repo and pipelines? Would like to be able to scan locally on a commit or before a push is accepted and also to scan repos and pipelines regularly. But, are open for suggestion on how to scan for secrets in the other ways.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below tools. Did you try it out

Answer (score -1):

You can check the secret scanners mentioned in [this blog](https://geekflare.com/github-credentials-scanner/).

For example the [Git Secrets](https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets#installing-git-secrets) released by AWS Labs.  You can install it on you local machine to scan your local commit and non-fast-forward merges. See [--install command](https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets#operation-modes)

To use `Git Secrets` in azure pipeline to scan azure devops repos. You can check out below steps:

1, Create [azure devops pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser).

2, If you want to use the scanner on Microsoft cloud agents. You need to install these scanner tools in the cloud agent machine in your pipeline. See below example: use `Git Secrets` on cloud agents.

Add a script task in your pipeline to install `Git Secrets` on cloud agents:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   #clone git-secrets repo in $(Agent.TempDirectory) folder
   cd $(Agent.TempDirectory)
   git clone "https://github.com/awslabs/git-secrets.git"
   cd git-secrets
   #install git-secrets
    ./install.ps1

   cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
   # Installs git hooks for source repository
   git secrets --install 
   #Adds a prohibited  pattern
   git secrets --add --literal 'iamthesecrecttoscan'
   #Scans for secrets
   git secrets --scan
   
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

You can also create [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on the machine where `Git Secrets` is installed(Or other scanner tools are installed). And then you can use the scanners directly in your pipeline without installing it in the pipeline, when you run your pipeline on this self-hosted agent.

3, Scan repos and pipelines regularly

You can use [scheduled triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#scheduled-trigger) in your pipeline to Scan your repos regularly.

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 12 * * 0"
  displayName: Weekly Sunday build
  branches:
    include:
    - releases/*
  always: true
```